# iOS7 Custom Done button on Numpad

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uibutton, ios7

I am wondering if someone has come across this situation of projecting a custom Done button in iOS7. I am successfully able to project the Custom Done button but still there is an issue. The issue is here :

The button is rendered on the numpad, but if you have any other Viewcontroller which is projecting `MFMailComposeViewController`, then if you are done with the mail controller (regardless of send or cancel), the Done button do not turn up next time if you try to show it on Numpad.

If someone need some more insight of problem, I can share up some screens & even Code.

Comment: How did you get the done button added onto the keyboard in iOS 7? I can't get it to work.

Comment: @GeorgeMcKibbin : Here is how the [done-button](https://s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/problem-arc/DoneButton.PNG) looks like once added to the keyboard in iOS7. If you are looking for similar behavior, I will post the code in a while.

Comment: Oh, yes please, that's exactly what I'm looking for.

Comment: @GeorgeMcKibbin : I have posted the answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20233101/1307844) to your actual Question